# How to add a line break for MSWORD YARG report

Tags: java, json, ms-word, line-breaks

I have a YARG MS Word template that has a placeholder like this.

```
${data}
```

And a json that looks like this

```
{
  "data": "1. One\n 2. Two\n 3. Three"
}
```

The problem is that in the generated report there are no line breaks that should be inserted instead of "\n". I tried to use "\r\n" but it's still ignored by the report generator.